# split function 'no instance for' error

Tags: haskell, split, tokenize

this function should tokenize a String:

```
    split s c xs i j =
        if head s == c
        then split s c (subStr s i j : xs) j (j + 1)
        else if j == length s
        then (subStr s i j) : xs
        else split s c xs i j + 1
    subStr s i j = take j(drop i s)
```

However I get the following error msg:
No instance for (Num [[Char]]) arising from a use of 'split'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration at (Num [[Char]])

Thanks.

Ok function is now:

```
split s c xs i j =
        if j == length s
        then (subStr s i j) : xs
        else if head (drop j s) == c
        then split s c (subStr s i j : xs) (j + 1) (j + 1)
        else split s c xs i (j + 1)

subStr s i j = take j(drop i s)
```

now when I apply the function with the following args: split "123,456,789" ',' [] 0 0 I get the result ["789", "456,789", "123"] what's happening here?

Comment: You should include your type signature for the function. It makes it a bit easier for us to tell what you're trying to do. but my initial guess is that you just need to parenthesize `j+1` on the second to last line.

Comment: I agree with cdk that this function could be rewritten more clearly. But if you just want this one to work, make `substr s i j = take (j-i) (drop i s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the line `else split s c xs i j + 1`. It seems like you're trying to add 1 to the result of `split`. You probably forgot parens around `(j + 1)`

I'll assume `split` returns a `[String]`, yes?

**Edit:** Your function is difficult to follow. The strange ordering is probably a result of you prepending substrings on the 3rd line `(subStr s i j) : xs`.

Try rewriting your function using `takeWhile, dropWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, or better yet, a proper string processing library like `ByteString` which provides

`Data.ByteString.Char8.split :: (Char -> Bool) -> ByteString -> [ByteString]`

Comment: Thanks, having a problem on logic now: so the function looks like this: split s c xs i j =
   if j == length s
   then (subStr s i j) : xs
   else if head (drop j s) == c
   then split s c (subStr s i j : xs) (j + 1) (j + 1)
   else split s c xs i (j + 1)
   
subStr s i j = take j(drop i s)  When I apply: split "123,456,789" 'c' [] 0 0 I get the output ["789", "456, 789", "123"] have any idea what's going on in the middle there?

Comment: I cannot read your code as you've presented it. So no, I have no idea what's going on. I recommend accepting this answer (once you're able to) and asking a new question regarding your problem.